# Time Complexity of Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

I've been trying to implement SVD in C for the past few weeks now, and currently I've been using the algorithm 6 found [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf), and from my understanding this algorithm will run in time O(n^5) because there are two loops (One of the loops does not go from 0 to n, I know but n^5 works as a crude bound), and inside the inner loop matrix multiplication has to be done which is an n^3 process.

However, according [this website](http://rakaposhi.eas.asu.edu/s01-cse494-mailarchive/msg00028.html), for an n by n matrix, SVD can be calculated in O(2n^3). Does anyone know where I can find an algorithm for that time complexity?

Comment: The close votes will probably stop if you restate "where can I find .. " to just asking for the algorithm directly

Answer (score 10):

In the event anyone is looking for an answer to this in the future, the algorithm to calculate SVD in O(n^3), if the matrix is a square matrix, is the method of Jacobi Rotations.

For more information on the specific algorithm you can look at Algorithm 7 on [this website](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf).

The notation on the website is a little confusing, because of the typos, but in the step when determining the values of d1, d2, c, and č (sorry that's the closest I could get to c with the hat on top), what they mean is that c = cos(theta), s = sin(theta), č = cos(phi) and š = sin(phi).

You can calculate these values of theta and phi by elimination and substitution or you can check out [this StackExchange post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/robust-algorithm-for-2x2-svd) to see how to calculate them.

After that it is just following that algorithm.

Comment: How did you work out the complexity O(n^3) from that paper?  Does it say anywhere or is it your own calculation?

Answer (score 4):

Computing the SVD of an m × n matrix has complexity O(mn min(n, m)). Since this is super-linear in the size of the data, it becomes computationally expensive for large data sets. However, if we have a low rank matrix, we would need only k basis vectors, where k << m, n. One way of computing the rank k approximation is to compute the SVD of the full matrix and retain only the k largest singular values and vectors.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.02812.pdf